# Reconnect Websocket

Tags: python, websocket

I am running a websocket to get data from phemex.

```
def run():
    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(listen())
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'WEBSOCKET CONNECTION CLOSED. RESTARTING..', e)
        time.sleep(2)
        run()

run()
```

My listen() function looks like this:

```
async def listen():
    url = "wss://phemex.com/ws"
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        sub_msg = "{\"id\":" + str(
            sequence) + ", \"method\": \"kline.subscribe\", \"params\":[\"" + symbol + "\"," 
            + str(kline_interval) + "]}"
        await ws.send(sub_msg)
        while True:
            msg = await ws.recv()
            msg = json.loads(msg)["kline"]
```

But now there is an error, that the event loop is actual running:

```
WEBSOCKET CONNECTION CLOSED. RESTARTING.. This event loop is already running
```

how can I close this loop and restart it?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you look at the socketio framework? It allows for automatic reconnection namely. See python implementation doc here : https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Is it not possible with websockets? I don‘t want to change from websockets to socket.

Comment: Socketio IS à websocket framework

Comment: so i am not a good programmer. So i can call a socket function into my except block, which says reconnet? So the only thing is that I have the find the right function for the reconnect?